# How to invoke Time Sheet Invoicing Upload SAP Fieldglass REST API call?

Tags: json, api, rest

I'm looking into how to use the [Time Sheet Invoicing Upload](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9cfd5c12ee3046d59453e73974f9c4b7/cloud/en-US/3800ae14e91144598852e3fe1ea25535.html) and first port of call was the [Try It Out](https://cloudintegration.hana.ondemand.com/api/timeSheetInvoicing/tryout) page.

[The documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9cfd5c12ee3046d59453e73974f9c4b7/cloud/en-US/3800ae14e91144598852e3fe1ea25535.html) lists the value for the mandatory "Type" field as `TIMESHEET INVOICING` but this seems at odds with other calls (it's usually just the call name, e.g. `Time Sheet Invoicing Upload`). Have tried these values and multiple other variants on the "Try It Out" page but all have failed so far with "The Type value specified in this file is not recognized".

Grateful for any pointers on how to get this working and/or advice on whether the SAP Fieldglass REST API documentation for this call might need to be amended.

*As an aside - am also wondering about some of the fields listed in the body - e.g. `TIMESHEET ID` and `ORIGINAL TIMESHEET ID` are in block capitals, which doesn't follow the convention of other fields and the [API reference](https://cloudintegration.hana.ondemand.com/api/timeSheetInvoicing/resource) for this call just has `"data": [ {} ]` in the body with no actual fields present - again, this is at odds with other calls.*

Answer (score 0):

**Re: Main question** - The documentation is incorrect - the `Type` value should be "Time Sheet Invoicing Upload". Also found out that this particular call can only be made by a Supplier tenant, not a Buyer tenant. In our case, we needed to request SAP to enable Configuration Manager for that tenant and then we could log in as the Supplier, change to the linked Configuration Manager account, create the API Application Key and License Key, enable the integration connector and use all of the above to authenticate as the Supplier and make the API call... it also requires a `Buyer` field in the header (set to the 4 digit Buyer code e.g. "A123") - this also isn't mentioned in the documentation.

**Re: Aside** - Turns out the API is case insensitive for field names - e.g. "Timesheet ID" will work just as well as "TIMESHEET ID".